# Why User Interface API is not available?

Tags: user-interface-api

I work on Performance Edition sandbox and I am System Administrator when I try to explore [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) and use workbench to send GET request to the following endpoint

> /services/data/v45.0/ui-api/

I receive the following error

[image]

> Service not found at: /services/data/v45.0/ui-api/

```
[ {
  "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
  "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
} ]
```

Am I missing anything? Should I grant myself any additional permissions to be able to execute and explore User Interface API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I got confused. Actually I do have access to User Interface API, but I should have tried to access endpoints like

> /services/data/v49.0/ui-api/object-info/

or

> /services/data/v49.0/ui-api/record-ui/0011g00000d6ePCAAY

I was wrong assuming that Service Not Found error is telling me that I don't have access to User Interface API.

Comment: Easy mistake to make, honestly. System returns 404 for anything that's not recognized, so long as you're authenticated.

Comment: @sfdcfox this is really confusing, since when you execute /services/data/v45.0 you receive list of endpoints available but ui-api is not present in that list for some strange reason and every other service has a root "/" endpoint like /sobjects, /tooling and every other api

Comment: Answer would be better if mentioned entire api base path: /services/data/v49.0/ui-api/object-info